# how to resolve this integral using partial fractions

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I cannot solve this, please help me and explain me!
$$\int \frac {2x-3} {x(2x+1)(2x-1)}\text{d}x$$

EDIT: I get this far

$$ \frac {2x-3} {x(2x+1)(2x-1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{2x+1}+\frac{C}{2x-1}$$

Comment: Did you actually try using partial fractions?

Comment: What should the partial fractions look like?  How can you find the constants involved?  Unless you show us what you tried, we cannot tell how to help you find your problem.

Comment: uh, ok I will add it

Answer (score 3):

Let us set $f(z)=\dfrac{2z-3}{z(2z+1)(2z-1)}$. Then:
$$\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=-\frac{1}{2}\right)=-2,$$
$$\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right)=3,$$
$$\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=\frac{1}{2}\right)=-1,$$
hence:
$$ f(z) = -\frac{2}{z+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{3}{z}-\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}$$
so:
$$ \int f(z)\,dz = C -2\log(z+1/2)+3\log z-\log(z-1/2).$$

Comment: It's amazing how "late" in partial fractions education one learns this trick. The OPer might not yet have seen it.

Comment: ha ha ha ha ......  Is someone who doesn't know how to do routine partial fractions expansions supposed to know about residues? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: to find the residue in a simple pole may be often simpler (to grasp, at least) than solving a system of equations. Obviously they are the same thing, so why not to provide an alternative view?

Comment: @Dr.MV: the residues are right and the decomposition too. Notice that I took $\frac{\text{Res}(\ldots)}{z-\frac{1}{2}}$ while you took $\frac{C}{2z-1}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes you did.  I decomposed as in the original post and missed your last expression.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick way to evaluate the coefficients of the partial fraction expansion. First we write

$$\frac{2x-3}{x(2x+1)(2x-1)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{2x+1}+\frac{C}{2x-1}\tag 1$$

Now, we find $A$ as follows.  Multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $x$ and take a limit of both resulting sides as $x \to 0$.  The left side is

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\,x\,\frac{2x-3}{x(2x+1)(2x-1)}=\frac{-3}{-1}=3$$

and the right side is

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\,x\,\left(\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{2x+1}+\frac{C}{2x-1}\right)=A$$

Thus, $A=3$

---

Now, we find $B$ similarly.  Multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $2x+1$ and take a limit of both resulting sides as $x \to -\frac12$.  The left side is

$$\lim_{x\to -1/2}(2x+1)\frac{2x-3}{x(2x+1)(2x-1)}=\frac{-4}{1}=-4$$

and the right side is

$$\lim_{x\to -1/2}\,(2x+1)\,\left(\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{2x+1}+\frac{C}{2x-1}\right)=B$$

Thus, $B=-4$

---

Finally, we find $C$ using the same approach.  Multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $2x-1$ and take a limit of both resulting sides as $x \to \frac12$.  The left side is

$$\lim_{x\to 1/2}(2x-1)\frac{2x-3}{x(2x+1)(2x-1)}=\frac{-4}{1}=-2$$

and the right side is

$$\lim_{x\to 1/2}\,(2x-1)\,\left(\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{2x+1}+\frac{C}{2x-1}\right)=C$$

Thus, $C=-2$

---

NOTE:  This approach is effectively the same as calculating residues. Yet, it relies on a perhaps more elementary exposition.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac {2x-3} {x(2x+1)(2x-1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{2x+1}+\frac{C}{2x-1}
$$
Let us add the fractions, using a common denominator:
\begin{align}
& \frac{A(2x+1)(2x-1) + Bx(2x-1) + Cx(2x+1)}{x(2x+1)(2x-1)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{(4A+2B+2C)x^2 + (-B+C)x + (-A-B+C)}{x(2x+1)(2x-1)}
\end{align}
The numerator, $(4A+2B+2C)x^2 + (-B+C)x + (-A-B+C)$, should be equal to the original numerator $0x^2+2x+(-3)$.  Hence we should have
\begin{align}
4A+2B+2C & = 0 \\
-B+C & = 2 \\
-A-B+C & = -3
\end{align}
Can you do the rest?

Comment: I believe that the third equation of the linear system is $-A=-3$.

Comment: @Dr.MV : How do you conclude that?

Comment: Sure.  Well, have a look at the numerator of the expression following " ... using a common denominator:"  The terms $Bx$ and $Cx$ are the leading terms and cannot give rise to constant terms - only linear and quadratic ones after multiplication by $(2x-1)$ and $(2x+1)$, respectively.